# How to install Perl Power Tools on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, perl

Are the Perl Power Tools still around? I'm trying to install them on Windows Server 2008 with Strawberry Perl. If I search the web I get:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ppt/

as first link, where I read "As of 2004-08-06, this project may now be found at http://ppt.perl.org". However http://ppt.perl.org is not working.

So I tried on CPAN and found

http://search.cpan.org/~sdague/ppt-0.12/PPT.pm

However if I try from **cpan** command line to install them with "install Bundle::PPT", I get the following:

```
Warning: Cannot install Bundle::PPT, don't know what it is.
Try the command

    i /Bundle::PPT/

to find objects with matching identifiers.
```

Running i /Bundle::PPT/ as suggested results in:

```
No objects found of any type for argument /Bundle::PPT/
```

Where can I get and how to install Perl Power Tools on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't install it with cpan either, but it worked with cpanminus if I was willing to skip the tests.

```
cpan App::cpanminus
cpanm Bundle::PPT
```

Note: I don't use Bundle::PPT, but I do use strawberry, and I'm just trying to help you get it installed.

Answer (score 3):

I've been updating the *Perl Power Tools* for the modern versions of perl, and I have given the distribution a better name: [PerlPowerTools](http://www.metacpan.org/module/PerlPowerTools). You should be able to install that distribution directly.

Part of my work is to test the code. Some of it is broken, some of it doesn't work with newer `perl`s, and some of it has dependencies that were never specified.